# My nested elements are throwing errors. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

The following block renders correctly in the Gutenberg's Block Editor.

```
registerBlockType('mytheme/rima-preface', {

    title: 'Custom block',
    description: 'My first block',
    category: 'layout',

    edit() {
        var blockProps = useBlockProps();

        return el("div", {
                class: "section"
            }, el("div", {
                class: "container"
            }, el("div", {
                    class: "row align-items-center col-spacing-50"
                }, el("div", {
                    class: "col-12 col-md-6"
                }, el("div", {
                    ...blockProps
                }, el(InnerBlocks)))
            )))
    },

    save() {
        var blockProps = useBlockProps.save();

        return el("div", {
                class: "section"
            }, el("div", {
                class: "container"
            }, el("div", {
                    class: "row align-items-center col-spacing-50"
                }, el("div", {
                    class: "col-12 col-md-6"
                }, el("div", {
                    ...blockProps
                }, el(InnerBlocks.Content)))
            )))
    }
});
```

However, as soon as I edit and save it, it shows the following errors on page reload:

```
Block validation: Expected attribute `class` of value `wp-block-mytheme-rima-preface`, saw `section`.

Block validation: Block validation failed for `mytheme/rima-preface` ({name: "mytheme/rima-preface", icon: {…}, keywords: Array(0), attributes: {…}, providesContext: {…}, …}).

Content generated by `save` function:

<div class="section" class="wp-block-mytheme-rima-preface"><div class="container"><div class="row align-items-center col-spacing-50"><div class="col-12 col-md-6"><div class="wp-block-mytheme-rima-preface"></div></div></div></div></div>

Content retrieved from post body:

<div class="section" class="wp-block-mytheme-rima-preface"><div class="container"><div class="row align-items-center col-spacing-50"><div class="col-12 col-md-6"><div class="wp-block-mytheme-rima-preface">

</div></div></div></div></div>
```

I've been trying to solve the issue for 30 minutes, anyone that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: of course as its try to tell you 
you have 2 attribute of class and it call the first one and he want it to be a specific class

Comment: @TalOrlanczyk which object has 2 class attributes?

Comment: <div class="section" class="wp-block-mytheme-rima-preface"><div class="container">
as you can see you have 2 class the code want to get the second one try to remove the class and see if its gonna work fine

Comment: @TalOrlanczyk Ah.. I see, thanks man! So the first "div" element should never have class attributes am I right?

Comment: no it can have a  class name but the problem is that you pass 2 attribute class and not only one  the code look for this class "wp-block-mytheme-rima-preface"  and instead he got  class="section" class="wp-block-mytheme-rima-preface" he search for the second class so try to remove this one so he can recoginzie is own class

Comment: @TalOrlanczyk Yes, but that's the output code which has 2 class attributes. Look at my own code, I only pass 1 class attribute myself.

Comment: yes but maybe the code somewhere it adds this class
but the thing is i dont super reconginze it as plan reactjs